# Python Client Isn't Outputting Anything from Server

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, client

I am just learning about networking and can't figure out why my computer isn't outputting what I expect.

I have created a simple server:

```
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)

user, address = s.accept()

print("Got connection from " + address)
```

and a client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5000

s.connect((host, port))
```

When I start up the server and then run the client code, I should see output "Got connection from [address]", but nothing happens. I also do not receive any error message. I am using Visual Studio Code on a Macbook Pro but have also tried this via Terminal.

I have had a friend test this same code on Windows and the output works as expected, so it doesn't seem like an issue with the code.

Is this a Mac issue? Something wrong with my configurations? I really appreciate the help. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Try running `lsof -i :5000` in the terminal. Is there already something running on this port?

Comment: Yes. I tried killing the process but maybe I am not doing it right because when I start up the server I get the error: OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use. When I change the socket, import socket keeps running forever and eventually times out.

Comment: To kill a process, use `kill -9 pid` where `pid` is the port (5000 in this case). Also, when you changed your port, did you change it in both the client and server code?

Comment: Thank you!! I got it to work properly. I was using a port that already had something running on it and I wasn't closing it out correctly.